# How to identify the LDAP connections in current environment (sharepoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

How to identify the LDAP connections in current environment (SharePoint 2010)

here we need why IDM server is migrating to higher version so if any one help us much appreciated?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you elaborate the issue.

Comment: in our organization they are migrating IDM 3.4 to higher version so we need to know where it will be impacted ?